# Parameterising color attribute of vpython sphere

Tags: colors, attributes, vpython

I'm trying to "parameterise" the attributes of the vpython sphere command. It all works fine except for the color attribute.

Story so far :-

```
for i in range(53):
    planet = objekt[i]
    col = colour[i]
    col = 'vector'+col[1:3]+','+col[3:4]+','+col[4:6]
    print planet, col
    planet = sphere(pos=vector(xcoord[i]*KM, ycoord[i]*KM, zcoord[i]*KM), 
    radius=radii[i], color=col)
```

where, objekt is a list of planet bodies, and colour is a list of colours in the format n,n,n where n can be either 0 or 1.

and I get error message :-

> > > ```
> > > Sun vector(1,1,0)
> > > ```

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Planet Orbits\SolarSystem-MajorandMinorPlanets(b).py", 
  line 66
    planet = sphere(pos=vector(xcoord[i]*KM, ycoord[i]*KM, zcoord[i]*KM), 
    radius=radii[i], color=col)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual_common\primitives.py", line 93, 
  in __init__
    self.process_init_args_from_keyword_dictionary( keywords )
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual_common\primitives.py", line 
  192, in process_init_args_from_keyword_dictionary
   self.color = keywords['color']
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    None.None(sphere, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    None(class cvisual::primitive {lvalue}, class cvisual::rgb)
```

> > >

Answer (score 1):

You constructed a character string and tried to use it where an actual vector is required. You need to do this:

col = vector(xcolor, ycolor, zcolor)